# Node JS request-promises POST method doesn't recognize a string

Tags: javascript, node.js, api

In order to connect my node.js module with another server I use 'request-promise' library. When I want to post something which looks like this:

```
rp.({
   method: 'POST',
   headers:{
    'Content-Type': 'text/plain',
    'Authorization': ''
},
   uri: 'https://myendpoint.com',
   body:{
     name: 'here is my a name',
     code: 'here is my code',
     location: 'here is my location'
   }
}).then(...)
```

But always when I try to use this function I get error message like this:

```
  RequestError: Error: Argument, error, options.body.
  TypeError: First argument must be a string or Buffer
```

All of my arguments in body are strings. Also I tried the same method on postman and that worked for me. So what I do wrong?

Comment: change `content-Type`: `application/json`

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can JSON stringify your object first and then pass it to the body parameter without needing to set the json parameter to true:

```
const myObject = {
    name: 'here is my a name',
    code: 'here is my code',
    location: 'here is my location'
};

const stringifiedObject = JSON.stringify(myObject);

rp.({
   method: 'POST',
   headers:{
    'Content-Type': 'text/plain',
    'Authorization': ''
   },
   uri: 'https://myendpoint.com',
   body: stringifiedObject
}).then(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

> ### POST data to a JSON REST API
>
> Set `option.body` to your data and `json: true` to encode the body as
>   JSON.

```
var options = {
    method: 'POST',
    uri: 'http://api.posttestserver.com/post',
    body: {
        some: 'payload'
    },
    json: true // Automatically stringifies the body to JSON
};
```

from: https://github.com/request/request-promise#post-data-to-a-json-rest-api